# Read in a file AS a single line

Tags: bash

[I have been struggling with an odbc connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72971027/isql-with-n-flag-for-newlines-in-input-file-gives-segmentation-fault-core-dum) and seemingly limited to being able to pass .sql query files that are on a single line.

e.g. If I pass a .sql file with the following content, things work great:

```
select * from `ourproject.ua.sometable` limit 10;
```

However, if the file looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ourproject.ua.sometable` 
LIMIT 10;
```

I get errors.

My command looks like this, where the queries above are in the file query.sql:

```
isql -v -b BigQuery < query.sql > data.txt
```

I wondered if there's a bash command work around solution where I could tell bash to read query.sql as a single line, or 'reduce' the file to a single line, before passing to `isql`.

Is this possible?

[edit]
I tried some solutions from [over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164056/how-do-i-combine-all-lines-in-a-text-file-into-a-single-line) but these seem to interpret the contents of the file as a command, whereas I need an intermediate step of getting them into one line before passing them to a command e.g.

```
echo `cat query.sql`
SELECT SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux.tar.gz bin bla.txt boot data.txt dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt opt proc query.sql root run sbin service.json srv sys tmp usr var FROM `ga4-extract.analytics_302644320.events_20220608` LIMIT 10;
```

Expected/wanted just a single line:

```
select * FROM `ga4-extract.analytics_302644320.events_20220608` LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? `tr '\012' ' ' <query.sql | sqli -v -b BigQuery > data.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @tripleee this gave me `tr -d '\012' query.sql | isql -v -b BQODBC > data.txt 
tr: extra operand 'query.sql'
Only one string may be given when deleting without squeezing repeats.
Try 'tr --help' for more information.
`

Comment: You missed the `<`

Comment: The `echo` without quotes is just [broken quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Bam! It works! (with `tr`) I'm reading your link on broken quoting... is it possible to use cat in that way somehow? See my edit for example

Comment: Seems like a really roundabout way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I liked the readability of using `cat`. E.g. this still returns a multi line output `echo "`cat query.sql`"`

Comment: I'm afraid Ask Ubuntu solutions tend to be unsophisticated if not outright broken.

Comment: I'll still with `tr` and do some reading, thanks very much for your help here